# Cant scroll on page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a page where the images in the page scroll but not the background and everything else. Everything is working fine except I can't scroll down the images! My current html is:

```css
td {
  padding: 0 0 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 9px sans-serif;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto 10px;
  max-width: 900px;
  outline: none;
}

@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,900");
@import url("font-awesome.min.css");

/* Basic */

.label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.label:hover {
  color: #afafaf;
  -moz-animation: spin .4s 1 linear;
  -o-animation: spin .4s 1 linear;
  -webkit-animation: spin .4s 1 linear;
  animation: spin .4s 1 linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

body,
input,
select,
textarea {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-weight: 300 !important;
  letter-spacing: -0.025em;
  line-height: 1.75em;
}

body {
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body.loading * {
  -moz-animation: none !important;
  -webkit-animation: none !important;
  -o-animation: none !important;
  -ms-animation: none !important;
  animation: none !important;
}

a {
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: dotted 1px;
  color: inherit;
  outline: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  border-color: transparent;
}


/* Icon */

.icon {
  position: relative;
}

.icon:before {
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: none !important;
}

.icon>.label {
  display: none;
}


/* Wrapper */

@-moz-keyframes wrapper {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes wrapper {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes wrapper {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes wrapper {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes wrapper {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#wrapper {
  -moz-animation: wrapper 3s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: wrapper 3s forwards;
  -o-animation: wrapper 3s forwards;
  -ms-animation: wrapper 3s forwards;
  animation: wrapper 3s forwards;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


/* BG */

#bg {
  -moz-animation: bg 60s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: bg 60s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: bg 60s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: bg 60s linear infinite;
  animation: bg 60s linear infinite;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  /* Set your background with this */
  background: #348cb2 url("images/bg.jpg") bottom left;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

@-moz-keyframes bg {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bg {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes bg {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes bg {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes bg {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
  }
}

#bg {
  background-size: 2250px auto;
  width: 6750px;
}


/* Overlay */

@-moz-keyframes overlay {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes overlay {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes overlay {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes overlay {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes overlay {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#overlay {
  -moz-animation: overlay 1.5s 1.5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: overlay 1.5s 1.5s forwards;
  -o-animation: overlay 1.5s 1.5s forwards;
  -ms-animation: overlay 1.5s 1.5s forwards;
  animation: overlay 1.5s 1.5s forwards;
  background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
  background-image: url("images/overlay-pattern.png"), url("images/overlay.svg");
  background-position: top left, center center;
  background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
  background-size: auto, cover;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Main */

#main {
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#main:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 1px;
}


/* Header */

@-moz-keyframes header {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes header {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes header {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes header {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes header {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes nav-icons {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes nav-icons {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes nav-icons {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes nav-icons {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes nav-icons {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 1em, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#header {
  -moz-animation: header 1s 2.25s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: header 1s 2.25s forwards;
  -o-animation: header 1s 2.25s forwards;
  -ms-animation: header 1s 2.25s forwards;
  animation: header 1s 2.25s forwards;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: default;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: -1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 90%;
}

#header h1 {
  font-size: 4.35em;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: -0.035em;
  line-height: 1em;
}

#header p {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  margin: 0.75em 0 0.25em 0;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

#header nav {
  margin: 1.5em 0 0 0;
}

#header nav li {
  -moz-animation: nav-icons 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
  -webkit-animation: nav-icons 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
  -o-animation: nav-icons 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
  -ms-animation: nav-icons 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
  animation: nav-icons 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 5.35em;
  line-height: 5.885em;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 5.35em;
}

#header nav li:nth-child(1) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 2.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
  -o-animation-delay: 2.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

#header nav li:nth-child(2) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 2.75s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.75s;
  -o-animation-delay: 2.75s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 2.75s;
  animation-delay: 2.75s;
}

#header nav li:nth-child(3) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  -o-animation-delay: 3s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

#header nav li:nth-child(4) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 3.25s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.25s;
  -o-animation-delay: 3.25s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 3.25s;
  animation-delay: 3.25s;
}

#header nav li:nth-child(5) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 3.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.5s;
  -o-animation-delay: 3.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 3.5s;
  animation-delay: 3.5s;
}

#header nav li:nth-child(6) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 3.75s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.75s;
  -o-animation-delay: 3.75s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 3.75s;
  animation-delay: 3.75s;
}

#header nav li:nth-child(7) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  -o-animation-delay: 4s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

#header nav li:nth-child(8) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 4.25s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.25s;
  -o-animation-delay: 4.25s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 4.25s;
  animation-delay: 4.25s;
}

#header nav li:nth-child(9) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 4.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.5s;
  -o-animation-delay: 4.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 4.5s;
  animation-delay: 4.5s;
}

#header nav li:nth-child(10) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 4.75s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.75s;
  -o-animation-delay: 4.75s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 4.75s;
  animation-delay: 4.75s;
}

#header nav a {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

#header nav a:before {
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: solid 1px white;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  height: 2.5em;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 2.5em;
}

#header nav a:hover {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

#header nav a:hover:before {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.175);
  color: white;
}

#header nav a:active {
  font-size: 0.95em;
  background: none;
}

#header nav a:active:before {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
  color: white;
}

#header nav a span {
  display: none;
}


/* Footer */

#footer {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 75%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 75%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 75%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 75%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 75%);
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: default;
  height: 6em;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 8em;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="bg"></div>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
  <div id="main">
    <!-- Header -->
    <header id="header">
```

Comment: Would you put this in a jsfiddle.net page?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4d0e4mma/

Comment: I created a fiddle from your code, please update it os we can see your problem. Currently there are no images and nothing to scroll.